# Heroku flask project flask db upgrade wrong database

Tags: python, flask, heroku, database-migration

I have a deployed Heroku app and database connected to it.

If I run `heroku pg:info` apart from else I see: **Tables: 0** meaning I have no tables on my database.

If I go to Heroku console and run `flask db upgrade` I receive an error that my relations already exist.

Environment variable `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` refers what I believe to be the correct database url and the contents of my `Procfile`:

```
web: flask db upgrade; source .env; gunicorn ridesharing:app
```

So it is clear that Heroku uses 2 different databases, the question is what I am doing wrong

Comment: If those are your real credentials you should invalidate them **_immediately_**. They are forever compromised, and you need to generate new ones. Editing them out of your question is _**not enough**_.

Comment: Aside: Why are you doing `flask db upgrade` in your `Procfile`? That should be run manually or as a release script, not as part of your web process. And why are you using an `.env` file? That file shouldn't be tracked; use Heroku's config vars instead.

Comment: Which database addon are you using? If it's Heroku Postgres, try running `heroku pg:links` to see what databases are linked to this app.

Comment: Valid comments. Running `heroku pg:links` shows connection to an empty database. So it does not really help

Comment: It just shows a single connection? If you run `heroku config`, how many variables do you see starting with `DATABASE_URL`? (If you have more than one, some should have colours appended, e.g. `DATABASE_URL_GREEN`.

Comment: yes it shows a single connection to the above mentioned database, `Heroku config` shows me only one `DATABASE_URL`